# Should x-forwarded-for contain a proxy in https traffic?

Tags: http, ssl, https, proxy

I have a web server cluster behind a proxy/load balancer.  That proxy contains my SSL certs and hands the web servers the decrypted traffic, and along the way adds an "x-forwarded-for" header into the HTTP header the web application receives.  This application has seen *millions* of IP addresses over the past decade, but something weird happened today.

For the first time, I saw an x-forwarded-for that contained a second address reach the application [addressed altered]:

```
 x-forwarded-for: 62.211.19.218, 177.168.159.85
```

This indicates that the traffic came through a proxy, and I understand this is normal for x-f-f.  I would have thought this was impossible (or at least unlikely) with https as the protocol.

Can someone explain how this is legit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [RFC 7239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239), this HTTP header is specified as

> **X-Forwarded-For:** client, proxy1, proxy2, ...

Where `client` is the IP of the original client and then each proxy adds the IP it received the request from, at the end of the list. In the above example, you would see IP of `proxy3` in your webserver and `proxy2` is the IP which connected to the `proxy3`.

As anyone can put anything inside this header, you should accept it only from known sources like your own reverse proxy or whitelist of known legit proxies. For example Apache has `mod_rpaf`, which transparently changes client IP address to the one provided in this header, but only if the request is received from the IP of known proxy server.

On corporate networks you can easily do transparent proxying for HTTPS traffic without any notice from normal users. Just create your own certification authority, use for example Windows Group Policy to install & trust this CA on all corporate workstations. Then redirect all HTTPS connections to your proxy which will generate certificate for all visited domains on the fly. This is something which is happening and you can even buy enterprise hardware proxies using this method.

So to summarize the reasons why you could see multiple IPs in the `X-Forwarded-For` header:

1. Transparent HTTPS proxy as mentioned above
2. The header was added by the requestor itself (browser, wget, script) for whatever reason, for example to hide its own IP
3. Some CDN like Cloudflare could add that header if used
4. Multiple reverse proxies defined either intentionally or by mistake

**Conclusion**: You should only trust this header if it originates from your own proxy (in case of multiple IPs, trust only the last one).

Comment: I think this answers what I wanted to know a bit more completely, and without actually sitting in the end-user's seat, I wouldn't know what certificate they're looking at anyway.  In a case like ours, 2 would be unlikely, 3 is not used, 4 is also not used.  So 1 remains the most likely remaining possibility.

Answer (score 0):

MAYBE it's using the Proxy protocol for HTTPS.  Granted you may not be using httproxy, but this seems to be a decent description:

http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt

I'm not sure about the SSL cert, but there's no guarantee someone is doing something pathalogical (maybe unintentionally) like running all their HTTPS traffic through a proxy and then accepting all the invalid certificates.  But I suspect the proxy protocol *might* make this work; it does expose the HTTP headers to the proxy in some sense.